# Swift Subscript Function - Allowing Multiple Return Types

Tags: swift, matrix

I am creating a Matrix library for swift that can support variable-dimensional matrices (not just your standard 2D matrix).

It is going quite well, however I am running into one problem

I would like the **subscript()** function to either return a value or an array of values.

So if you have a simple 2D matrix like this:

```
let a : Matrix<Int> = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]] // constructs a Matrix
```

And the user subscripts into this matrix like this:

```
b = a[1, 0] //returns 4
```

However if the user subscripts like this:

```
b = a[1] //returns [4, 5, 6]
```

So essentially I would like this function to have two possible return types depending on context. I would like to do this without having to return a tuple/enum/etc. so that it just automatically infers the return types based on the dimensions of the matrix. Is this possible?

Comment: Idk if Swift had Union types, but that could be an option here. It's usually advisable to only return a single type though

Comment: Just write multiple subscripts with your desired amount of params. You could likely find a way to do it with one, but it would likely require a lot more work and complicate your code an unnecessary amount.

Comment: Will your matrix hold just instances and arrays of a given type? Or could your example above be modified to include strings as well as ints?

Comment: Mike Taverne: My matrix library can hold any type. However if you intend to perform mathematical operations on the matrix it has to be a Numeric type (ie. Int or Float)

Comment: PEEJWEEJ: The problem is that whether you're using a 2D matrix or a 5D matrix, the type will always be Matrix<Int> for example. Internally the data is simply stored in a 1D array. I have decided to just set 'Any' as the subscript return type so I can return an n-dimensional array or a scalar value

Comment: You know what? I think I will simply return a Matrix object from the subscript function, and make it so that a Matrix can hold even a single scalar value. That is probably the best solution here

Answer (score 1):

You're close, here's something to get you started.

I return an optional to avoid crashing from an index range error.

```
extension Array {
    var bounds : (Int, Int) {
        get {
            return (0, self.count - 1)
        }
    }
}

extension Array where Element == Array<Int> {


    subscript(first: Int, second: Int) -> Int? {
        get {
            guard !self.isEmpty else { return nil }
            guard first <= bounds.1 else { return nil }
            let it = self[first]
            guard second <= it.bounds.1 else { return nil }
            return it[second]
        }
    }
}


let one = [[1, 0], [3, 4]]
print(one[1, 0]) // => Optional(3)
```

Comment: Internally in my matrix library, the data is stored in a single 1D array, to make calculations fast.

This is a good idea if my library were making use internally of multiple dimension arrays but it is not. 

Currently I have decided to just make 'Any' the return type. I'd prefer a better solution but this is the only thing I can think of.

Comment: So essentially, whether you are creating a 2D matrix or a 5D matrix, the type will always be Matrix<Int> or Matrix<Float> for example. The only difference is that the 'shape' parameter array will have 5 elements instead of 2

Comment: Yeah my approach would work with the generic declaration you mention here. I wasn't sure if that was too broad for you, but i'll try some other ideas i've thought of today. Ill get back on this shortly